# How to mock a method call of a struct in test case at go

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

Here is the sample code for the struct and its method

```
type A struct {}

func (a *A) perfom(string){
...
...
..
}
```

Then i want to call the method from the function `invoke()` residing outside the package, sample code

```
var s := A{}
func invoke(url string){
   out := s.perfom(url)
   ...
   ...
}
```

I want to write the test case for the  function `invoke` by mocking the `perform` method of A.

In java, we have mockito, jmock framework to stub method calls.

Is there any way in go, we can mock the method call of the struct without introducing `interfaces` in source code ?

Comment: Don't mock it. (You cannot anyway.) Actually perform it. If performing the method would reach out: Mock that, e.g. a HTTP endpoint with net/http/httptest. Or have a global which can be turned to a fake during test (like a var Now func() time.Time = time.Now). Don't mock. This is bad practice.

Comment: I totally agree with you, but i need to mock some real grpc  calls

Comment: Still: do not mock. Use a type B instead of A during test and let B provides a fake. Don't mock.

Comment: "Use a type B instead of A during test and let B provides a fake" - how is that different from mocking? "Mock objects are simulated objects that mimic the behavior of real objects in controlled ways."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To mock a method call, you need to make a mock of your structure.

With the code example you provided, I would recommend making a `Performer` interface that implements your `Perform` call. Both your real structure and your mock structure would implement this interface.

I would also recommend passing your structure as an argument to the invoke function instead of using a global variable.

Here is an example:

```
type Performer interface {
    perform()
}

type A struct {
}

func (a *A) perform() {
    fmt.Println("real method")
}

type AMock struct {
}

func (a *AMock) perform () {
    fmt.Println("mocked method")
}

func caller(p Performer) {
    p.perform()
}
```

In your tests, inject the mock to your `invoke` call.
In your real code, inject the real structure to your `invoke` call.

Using a library like https://godoc.org/github.com/stretchr/testify/mock you will even be able to really easily verify that your method is called with the right arguments, called the right amount of times, and control the mock's behavior.

Comment: wanted some way without using interface ,is it possible to achieve the behavior with out interface ?

Comment: Since you currently use a global, yeah. You just need to set `performer := &realStruct{}` above your `invoke` call, and when running your tests, set the global `performer` variable to `&mockStruct{}`. Other than that, keep the two structure definitions and their methods. Note however, that this is not very idiomatic. Using interfaces **is** the right solution, and this is a workaround.

Comment: See [this playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/_96hfUAj8az) (note that you can't run this on playground, as it will work only if you use this method between multiple files.)

Answer (score 3):

Assign the `Perfom` method to a global variable and re-assign it with a mocked one before running the test.

E.g.

`51760447/a/a.go`:

```golang
package a

type A struct{}

func (a *A) Perfom(url string) (string, error) {
    return "real data", nil
}
```

`51760447/caller.go`:

```golang
package caller

import "github.com/mrdulin/golang/src/stackoverflow/51760447/a"

var s = a.A{}
var (
    Perfom = s.Perfom
)

func Invoke(url string) string {
    out, _ := Perfom(url)
    return out
}
```

`51760447/caller_test.go`:

```golang
package caller_test

import (
    "reflect"
    "testing"

    caller "github.com/mrdulin/golang/src/stackoverflow/51760447"
)

func TestInvoke(t *testing.T) {
    oPerfom := caller.Perfom
    perfomCallCount := 0
    caller.Perfom = func(url string) (string, error) {
        perfomCallCount++
        return "fake data", nil
    }
    defer func() {
        caller.Perfom = oPerfom
    }()
    got := caller.Invoke("localhost")
    want := "fake data"
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(got, want) {
        t.Errorf("should return fake data, got:%v, want: %v", got, want)
    }
    if !reflect.DeepEqual(perfomCallCount, 1) {
        t.Errorf("Perfom method should be called once, got:%d", perfomCallCount)
    }
}
```

unit test result:

```sh
=== RUN   TestInvoke
--- PASS: TestInvoke (0.00s)
PASS
coverage: 100.0% of statements
ok      github.com/mrdulin/golang/src/stackoverflow/51760447    0.033s
```

coverage report:

[image]