# Mocking a struct's method call in go tests

Tags: go, testing, methods, struct, mocking

I am looking to mock a method of a struct in tests to improve code coverage.
There are a few posts regarding this, none of them are working for me. I might have gotten this completely wrong.

`main/file1.go`

```
type application struct {
    Name string
 }

func (app *application) find() error {
    // perform function logic
    return nil
}

func main() {
    app := &application{
        Name:   "Main Application",
    }

    err := app.find()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error in find call: %s\n", err)
    }
}
```

I need to be able to mock test for `find()` and return an `error` (I would not want to generate a test case that could result in an error as this is not under my control and I am not sure how to generate one by passing acceptable params).
I tried to follow the second answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51760447/how-to-mock-a-method-call-of-a-struct-in-test-case-at-go) post and the compiler is not liking it.

`main/file1_test.go`

```
func Test_application_find(t *testing.T) {
    tests := []struct {
        name           string
        app            *application
        wantErr        string
    }{
        {
            name: "generate error",
            app: &application{
                Name: "Mock Application",
            },
            wantErr: true,
        },
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        mockCaller := tt.app.find // this works fine
        tt.app.find = func() error { // this assignment errors out
            return fmt.Errorf("Mock Error Message")
        }
        defer func() {
            tt.app.find = mockCaller // this assignment errors out
        }()

        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if err := tt.app.find(); (err != nil) && (err.Error() != "Mock Error Message") {
                    t.Errorf("error = %s, wantErr %s", err.Error(), tt.wantErr)
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

There are several ways to mock a method. They all have situations they are good for.

### Composition

For the tests you create a new struct on top of the original.

```golang
struct testApp struct{
    application
}
```

Now `teststruct` behaves almost the same way as `app`, but you can overwrite the find function:

```golang
func (app *testApp) find() error {
    return errors.New("some error")
}
```

In the test you initialize the `testApp` with a proper `app` given to it:

```golang
app := testApp{
    application: &application{
        Name: "Mock Application",
    }
}
```

Now you can write your tests on the `app` variable.

Note that this will not work for all use cases since composition is not inheritance. Calling a function on the original `application` will not call the new `find` function in `testApp`.

### Interface

You can also mock the entire application struct / the parts you need for your tests. This mostly makes sense if you want to test another struct with a dependency on `application`.

The struct to be tested should not use `application` directly but an interface of the functionality it needs. (This might mean refactoring your code to do so.)

Then create a mock with the mocked `find` function and pass the mock to the struct to be tested:

```golang
type app interface{
    find() error
}

type mockApp struct{
    Name string
}

(s *mockApp) find() error {
    return errors.New("some error")
}
```

### Struct Field

You could also make the `find` function a struct field. Then you can overwrite it for test purposes. That however has the downside of having to change the code.

```golang
type application struct {
    Name string
    find func() error
}
```

Write a creator to be able to still initialize the struct in a reasonable fashion:

```golang
func newApplication() *application {
    return &application{
        Name: "Main Application",
        find: func() error {
            // perform function logic
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can overwrite the `find` method (actually it is a field now) in your tests:

```golang
app := newApplication()
app.find = func() error {
    return errors.New("some error")
}
```

Comment: In my opinion the `interface` is the most go-like approach. If that means you are mocking away code you want to test, then think about splitting the code into multiple structs: The code (`application`) you want to test and a `finder` struct/interface that you want to mock away. It seems to me, `find` is more of a dependency. You also said, that you can't influence the outcome of it easily.

Comment: Feel free to mark it as the correct answer, if it helped you.