# How to unit test a struct method by mocking another method on the same struct?

Tags: unit-testing, go, struct, interface, mocking

I have a struct:

```
type Domain struct{}
```

And multiple methods on it:

```
func (d *Domain) A() {
    d.B()
}


func (d *Domain) B() {
    d.C()
    d.D()
    ...
}
```

I want to test method `A` by mocking call to method `B`. But I am not sure how that can be done when methods are on the same struct?

I have seen other approaches to define interface and corresponding struct (e.g. here: [How to mock a method call of a struct in test case at go](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51760447/5353128)). But here I can't move my methods to other struct just for mocking it.

Any reference/help would be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but consider not mocking at all.

Comment: Then how do I unit test it? I mean I have some network call in `B` which I want to mock.

Comment: Do the "network call" to a fake/stub.

Comment: Regardless of whether the "another method" is on the same struct or not, it is simply not possible to mock a concrete method, period.

Comment: See the https://pkg.go.dev/net/http/httptest package to implement the fake/stub. If not using HTTP but another network protocol, the same approach is still valid. Assuming it is HTTP, you would need to inject in Domain (at construction) httptest.Server.URL (once you get the hang of it, it is _that_ simple!)

Answer (score 0):

As the other users mentioned you cannot do the mock as you are thinking but what you can do is to have a mockable dependency using a strategy pattern. As for example:

```
type Strategy Interface {
   func DoTheBJob
}

type Domain struct{
   Sttg Strategy
}

func (d *Domain) A() {
    d.B()
}


func (d *Domain) B() {
   d.Sttg.DoTheBJob(d)
}
```

**On production**: A strategy which has some logic

```
type ProductionStrategy struct{}

func (s *ProductionStrategy) DoTheBJob(domain *Domain) {
   domain.C()
   domain.D()
   ...
}

d := Domain{
   strategy: ProductionStrategy{},
}
```

**On Tests**: A strategy which does what you want

```
type TestStrategy struct{}

func (s *TestStrategy) DoTheBJob(domain *Domain) {
   // some testable behavior
   ...
}

d := Domain{
   strategy: TestStrategy{},
}
```